# Android ImageButton swap resource leaves 'residue'

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have 2 Images:

IMG_1:

[image]

IMG_1_PRESSED:

[image]

I display IMG_1 by default, but when I click on it, the image should change to IMG_1_PRESSED.

Here's a code snippet of the button itself, where `be` is an `enum` containing the correct drawables:

```
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this.context);
    
    ib.setImageResource(be.getDrawable());
    ib.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    ib.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ib.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    
    ib.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    ib.setMaxWidth(width);
    ib.setMaxHeight(height);

    setStrengthListener(ib, be);
```

And here is the `setStrengthListener` method:

```
private void setStrengthListener(final ImageButton ib, final ButtonEnum be){
    ib.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ib.setImageResource(be.getDrawablePressed());
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ib.setImageResource(be.getDrawable());
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Now both images are 480x240 and `width` and `height` are set to device's width/3 and device's width/6 respectively (I want to display 3 images, hence the /3).

Here's the problem, if the button is pressed, I get this:

[image]

There's this little line under the pressed button... I've tried a lot to fix this but somehow that little line has made itself my greatest enemy today.

As an extra effort: the line doesn't show anymore if I set the original resource to IMG_1_PRESSED:

```
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this.context);
    
    ib.setImageResource(be.getDrawablePressed());
    ib.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    ib.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ib.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    ....etc
```

But obviously I don't want to start with a pressed button.

So dear Android experts, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a hell of a lot of trial and error, I managed to get that grey line away. In the end it was very simple really, though I'm not completely sure why this fixed it:

**The main layout**:

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

**The view creation** (layout for imageview is unchanged):

```
ImageView iv = tbb.getTopBarButton(ButtonEnum.IMG_1);

LinearLayout iViewLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
iViewLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
iViewLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

iViewLayout.addView(iv);

ll.addView(iViewLayout);
```

Adding a separate layout per imageview seemed to remove the grey line. Would love to know WHY this works though, but for future reference, at least I hope to help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution as i know, 
Try this

create Xml inside your *Drawable* folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed_img"android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal_image" />
</selector>
```

Then add this *drawable* file as background to your `View`

Example :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/enter_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="100dip"
    android:maxWidth="100dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/enter_btn" />
```

or in Java code

```
yourView.setImageResource(R.drawable.*drawablefile*);
```

You can use `ImageButton` also but `ImageView` would look better than `ImageButton` since it doesn't have button borders.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I switched to ImageView, didn't make sense to use a button. The problem still remained however, but after a couple (7) hours of trial, error and reading, I figured it out. I'll write down the solution in an answer =)